# JQ/JS trouble accessing DOM ID element by ID in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

From the parent, I have opened a new window called win2. I am trying to change the text in a DIV with an ID of title. I can access video player elements to play a video but for some reason, for the life of me cannot figure out how to change the text:

```
var extS = $(win2.document).contents().find('#videosource'); //works fine
var extP = $(win2.document).contents().find('#videoplayer'); //works fine
var extT = $(win2.document).contents().find('#Title'); //doesn't work


extP.get(0).pause();
extS.attr('src', PlayMe);
extP.get(0).load();
extS.get(0).play(); //this all works fine
extT.html('Now Playing'); //doesn't work
```

Also tried:

```
 $(win1.document).getElementById('#Title').html('Now Playing'); //doesn't work
```

Here is the HTML on the child window:

```
<html>
<head> 
<title>Video Window</title>
<link href="CSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">

    <div class="videocontent">
    <div class="currentvideo"></div>
    <div class="VideoWindowTitle" id="Title">Video Window</div>
    <video id="videoplayer" autoplay loop poster="Blank Video.png" width="100%">
        <source id="videosource" src="" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try $(win1.document).getElementById('#Title').innerHTML = "Now Playing";

Comment: `var extT.html('Now Playing');` syntax error

Comment: remove ```#``` form ```getElementById``` method 
 call (```document.getElementById('Title')```)

Comment: thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately none of these suggestions or a combination of the two seem to work. also, thanks - somehow that var snuck in when I copied it over.

Comment: It would be useful to see your HTML

Comment: thanks, added HTML of child window. I have tried other ID names as well, in case using "Title" was throwing it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this should be a warning on attention to detail.

The following worked:

```
var extT = $(win1.document).contents().find('#displayvideo')

exT.html(title);
```

The issue was that the html video player was set to autoplay and would break the script when I then executed play through the  attribute. I was trying to run this particular html change AFTER that point of course. So everything would work fine up to that point and I neglected to troubleshoot properly.